# Spring Data Streamable vs Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I know what is the purpose and how to handle Stream as a query output, i.e.:

```
Stream<Person> findAll();
```

However, recently I stumbled upon `org.springframework.data.util.Streamable<T>`, used in the same way as a `Stream`:

```
Streamable<Person> findByNameContaining(String name, Sort sort);
```

What is the use case of `Streamable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**interface Streamable**

> Functional Interface: This is a functional interface and can therefore
> be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method
> reference.

[Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/Streamable.html)

Stream from `java.util` is just an interface.

Streamable was created from Spring as a functional interface that extended `Iterable<T>`

Streamable also has some default methods and some static ones. But it was used to be able to provide an Iterator as a lambda function taking advantage of how functional interfaces work.

That's only technical info.

Practical now from what I understand it's main use is to convert an `Iterable<T>` into a `Stream<T>`

```
    Iterable<String> it = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
    Stream<String> s = Streamable.of(it).stream();
```

It didn't exist an easy way to directly convert an `Iterable<T>` into a `Stream<T>` therefore they invented it.

You can find most of those uses here  [Uses of Spring Streamable](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.data.util.Streamable/of)

Comment: thanks! And how about handling - does it need to be annotated with `@Transactional` like methods returning a `Stream`?